# formatting number in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

Im using this code for formatting my textbox.

```
Public Function TextFormat(ByVal sString As String) As String
        Dim num1 As Decimal
        Try
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(sString)
            TextFormat = FormatNumber(num1, 2)
            Return TextFormat
        Catch
            TextFormat = sString
        End Try
    End Function
```

-the problem is its rounding off the number i input .. 
sample

textbox.text = "5999.99"
it displaying "6000.00"
how can i disable the auto rounding off number . or is there any other code for formatting text? "###,###,###.##" << it should be like this

thanks

Answer (score 2):

use ToString Instead FormatNumber.

```
Public Function TextFormat(ByVal sString As String) As String
    Dim num1 As Decimal
    If Double.TryParse(sString, num1) Then
        Return num1.ToString("G") ' or ToString("F2") or ToString("0.00") 
    Else
        Return sString
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
 Dim number = Math.Truncate(CInt(textbox.text) * 1000) / 1000;

 textbox.text = number.toString
```